# mysql like groupby in oracle how to

Tags: mysql, oracle

In Mysql i have the fdllowing query along with the results below

```
drop table tab1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tab1 
(col1 integer,col2 integer(10),col3 varchar(10),col4 integer)engine=memory
insert into tab1
values(100,1,'Hello',9);
insert into tab1
values(200,1,'HelloWrld',8);
insert into tab1
values(300,1,'HelloTher',7);
insert into tab1
values(400,2,'HiThere',6);
insert into tab1
values(500,3,'Howdy',5);
insert into tab1
values(600,3,'Hiya',4);

select col1,col2,col3,col4,min(col4)
from tab1
group by col2

'100', '1', 'Hello', '9', '7'
'400', '2', 'HiThere', '6', '6'
'500', '3', 'Howdy', '5', '4'
```

In Oracle i want the same result as Mysql

```
with tab1 as (
 select 100 col1, 1 col2, 'Hello' col3,9 col4  from dual
 union all
 select 200 col1, 1 col2, 'HelloWrld' col3,8 col4  from dual
 union all
 select 300 col1, 1 col2, 'HelloTher' col3,7 col4  from dual
 union all
 select 400 col1, 2 col2, 'HiThere' col3,6 col4  from dual
 union all
 select 500 col1, 3 col2, 'Howdy' col3,5 col4  from dual
 union all
 select 600 col1, 3 col2, 'Hiya' col3,4 col4  from dual
 )
 select min(col1),col2,min(col3),col4,min(col4)
 from tab1
 group by col2,col4

Result I get is this
 MIN(COL1)       COL2 MIN(COL3)       COL4  MIN(COL4)
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
       100          1 Hello              9          9
       200          1 HelloWrld          8          8
       500          3 Howdy              5          5
       600          3 Hiya               4          4
       300          1 HelloTher          7          7
       400          2 HiThere            6          6
```

**What i would like to have is this**

```
'100', '1', 'Hello', '9', '7'
'400', '2', 'HiThere', '6', '6'
'500', '3', 'Howdy', '5', '4'
```

How do i achieve Mysql like group by in Oracle 
I am unable to get this and this is part of a long query that i am trying to resolve

Comment: The result for MySQL is [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve.  The two queries have different `group by` clauses.  Are you trying to get the min for every column, one column, or something else?

Comment: @MarkByers - And it's one of the worst behaviors to allow, in my opinion.  I think I'd rather have some special syntax to denote that (say, `GROUP BY col1, HIDDEN(col2)` or something) to make the behavior explicit.  As it is, if you just mis-type something, your results are potentially bad, and it doesn't even _warn_ you.

Comment: Mark i followed the link but couldn't make sense of it other then the query being illegal in Standard SQL and Mysql is free to choose free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate Does this mean oracle cannot do what Mysql can do in plain english

Comment: Mark Thanks for the link and ending my agony i was struggling since last 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your intention is to get a deterministic result (unlike the MySQL result which is not deterministic) and that the `col1` - `col4` data you want to retain is the data for the row with the smallest `col1` value for a given `col2` value, you can use analytic functions

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with tab1 as (
  2   select 100 col1, 1 col2, 'Hello' col3,9 col4  from dual
  3   union all
  4   select 200 col1, 1 col2, 'HelloWrld' col3,8 col4  from dual
  5   union all
  6   select 300 col1, 1 col2, 'HelloTher' col3,7 col4  from dual
  7   union all
  8   select 400 col1, 2 col2, 'HiThere' col3,6 col4  from dual
  9   union all
 10   select 500 col1, 3 col2, 'Howdy' col3,5 col4  from dual
 11   union all
 12   select 600 col1, 3 col2, 'Hiya' col3,4 col4  from dual
 13   )
 14  select col1,
 15         col2,
 16         col3,
 17         col4,
 18         min_col4
 19    from (select col1,
 20                 col2,
 21                 col3,
 22                 col4,
 23                 min(col4) over (partition by col2) min_col4,
 24                 rank() over (partition by col2 order by col1) rnk
 25            from tab1)
 26*  where rnk = 1
SQL> /

      COL1       COL2 COL3            COL4   MIN_COL4
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
       100          1 Hello              9          7
       400          2 HiThere            6          6
       500          3 Howdy              5          4
```

Comment: Hi Justin What is meant by nondeterministic If run the query twice i will not get the same result is that what you mean

Comment: @jhon.smith - There is the potential to get different results, yes.  Realistically, if you run the query twice when there have been no changes to the table, you'll likely get the same result.  But eventually, you'll likely get a different result.  That may happen tomorrow, it may happen a year from now, it may happen when you upgrade your database.

Comment: Justin I have to mark your answer as correct wish stackoverflow allows me to mark two correct answers as Mark Byers is technically correct too not to take the credit from Mark

Answer (score 2):

According to the mysql documentation, the results for columns not specified in the group by can come from any rows.

So, a perfectly reasonable query in Oracle is:

```
 select min(col1),col2,min(col3),min(col4),min(col4)
 from tab1
 group by col2
```

If your mysql code was depending on a particular value being chosen, then that code is broken.  You will need to figure out exactly what you want, and figure out how to get that in Oracle.